# Deep face gives error saying ValueError: ('Confirm that ', 'Just Me.png', ' exists')

Tags: python, deepface

Ok so I am trying to make a face recognition login system but I keep on getting the same error.

Here is my code:

> ```
> import cv2
> import pyttsx3
> from deepface import DeepFace
>
> def take_picture():
>     print("Scanning Face...")
>     cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>     ret, frame = cap.read()
>     cv2.imwrite("img1.jpg", frame)
>     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
>     cap.release()
>     print("Face Scan Complete")
>
>
> take_picture()
> img1 = "img1.jpg"
> img2 = "Just Me.png"
>
> model_name = "Facenet"
>
> authentication = DeepFace.verify(img1_path=img1, img2_path=img2, model_name=model_name, enforce_detection=False)
>
> # print(authentication['verified']):
> if authentication['verified']:
>     print("Access Granted")
> else:
>     print("Access Denied.")**
> ```

And here is the error i am getting:

> Scanning Face... [ WARN:0@38.046] global
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp
> (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB
> terminating async callback Face Scan Complete 1/1
> [==============================] - 9s 9s/step Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\JARVIS\JARVIS_FACE_RECOGNITION.py", line 30,
> in 
> authentication = DeepFace.verify(img1_path=img1, img2_path=img2, model_name=model_name, enforce_detection=False)   File
> "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py",
> line 170, in verify
> img2_representation = represent(img_path = img2_path   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py",
> line 754, in represent
> img = functions.preprocess_face(img = img_path   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\deepface\commons\functions.py",
> line 175, in preprocess_face
> img = load_image(img)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\deepface\commons\functions.py",
> line 90, in load_image
> raise ValueError("Confirm that ",img," exists") ValueError: ('Confirm that ', 'Just Me.png', ' exists')

Comment: "Just Me.png" is really in the same folder of that python program? If yes, try not to use blank character in the file such as "JustMe.png".

Comment: thank you for responding, it was in the same directory and i tried using no blank characters but still did not work

Comment: i managed to fix the error but now the problem is it says access granted ti everyone :/